# Vector question-sum of the integers

Tags: vectors

If a and b are two unit vectors, then the sum of the integers in the range of $\frac{5}{2}|a+b|+6|a-b|$ is

(1) 0

(2) 25

(3) 64

(4) 81

Comment: perhaps you can add more information about the question, like what is the background and why it matters to you. And the statement also seems a little fishy, or let us say it seems it lacks necessary information.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This is an answer suitable for multiple choice questions only.

Let, $$f(a,b)=\frac{5}{2}|a+b|+6|a-b|$$

For $b=a$, $f(a,b)=5$, for $b=-a$, $f(a,b)=12$. So the range of $f$ is atleast $[5,12]$. Sum of integrs from 5 to 12 is
$$\frac{12*13}{2}-\frac{4*5}{2}=68$$

Therefore the only remaining choice is 81.

Comment: But the range may not include all of [5,12] no? It may not be connected.

Comment: Perhaps none of the above?

Comment: Do you happen to have an explanation?